# Trouble Adding Arrow Icon to Tooltip-Wrapper

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to add an arrow icon to a tooltip-wrapper using HTML and CSS, but I'm encountering difficulties getting the arrow icon to display properly. I've followed multiple approaches and suggestions, but the arrow icon remains invisible. I'd greatly appreciate some guidance on what might be causing this issue.

Eventually I'm trying to to smth like in this image.

[image]

What I've Tried:

Added a ::after pseudo-element with appropriate styling to the .tooltip-wrapper class.

- Experimented with different border styles, colors, and dimensions for the arrow icon.
- Ensured the pseudo-element has content and dimensions using content: '';, width: 0;, and height: 0;.

The problem looks like to occure because of the `overflow-auto`.
Do I need another wrapper element?

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.tooltip-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parent:hover .tooltip-wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip-content {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
}

.tooltip-wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  border-color: red transparent red transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <section>
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
      tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
      voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
      clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
      <div class="parent">
        <span class="tooltip-wrapper">
          <span class="tooltip-content">
            sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliquyam
          </span>
        </span>
        hello world
      </div>
      sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
      erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet.
    </section>

    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-tdd-odr5yo?file=/src/styles.css) to play around

Comment: where do you want the arrow icon to be displayed?

Comment: @Greg I want it to be displayed at the bottom of the tooltip box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, as I wasn't sure about what you were looking for exactly. Now, I think it is just what you wanted. Necessary comments are included.

```css
/* creating some space on the top */
section{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.parent {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.tooltip-wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 20px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: max-content;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: -70px;
}

.parent:hover .tooltip-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip-content {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
}

.parent::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 8px 10px 8px;
    border-color: blue transparent blue transparent;
    /* for vertical flip */
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);

    /* left positioning */
    left: 35px;
    display: none;
}

/* bottom blue background */
.parent::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 190px;
    height: 10px;
    background: blue;
    left: -60px;
    bottom: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

/* displaying pseudo elements on hover */
.parent:hover::before, .parent:hover::after{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
    tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
    clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
    <div class="parent">
        <span class="tooltip-wrapper">
        <span class="tooltip-content">
            sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliquyam
        </span>
        </span>
        hello world
    </div>
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
    erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
    rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet.
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
Overflow is disapppeared, and reverting position absolute makes style wrong.

Comment: OK, I think you have to create the pseudo element on the `.parent` instead of the `.tooltip-wrapper` and I also have created another pseudo element `::before` to cover the bottom texts with the background blue color.

Comment: this doesn't work properly. Check the sandbox link, i just updated the code with your changes.

Comment: In other words words try to make it work on hover

Comment: @FD3 I think now I got it right :) Actually, I wasn't sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The code and the implementation is good ,but i suggest you to change the `border-color` field in `.tooltip-wrapper::after` to this.

```
border-color: red transparent red transparent;
```

Try this and let me know that it fixed or not.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't change anything.
Here is https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-tdd-odr5yo?file=/src/styles.css link. You can test there.
Arrow should be in the bottom of tooltip content.